# Generating Simple List from 1 to 10 with haskell

Tags: list, haskell, counter, increment

I am new in Haskell, could guys help me how to generating list from 1 to 10.

I tried to make like this:

```
seqList :: Integer -> [Integer]
seqList 1 = [1]
seqList n = n : seqList(n-1)
```

The result 10 to 1, not 1 to 10

And second question
can we make function as value.

```
numList :: [Integer]
numList =  [1,2..10]
totJum :: Int
totJum = length numList

takeNum :: Int->[Integer]
takeNum totJum
  | totJum >= 10 = take 5 numList
  | totJum == 10  = numList
```

With this code, i want to call output if the length from numlist matches the condition.

Comment: remove the `totJum` in the head of the `takeNum` function (and thus use `[Integer]` as signature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one you can work with an *accumulator*: a variable you use to yield a value and each time increment in the recursive call, so:

```
seqList :: Integer -> [Integer]
seqList n = go 1
    where go i
              | i <= … = …
              | otherwise = …
```

where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.

> with this code, I want to call output if the length from numlist matches the condition.

You should not use `totJum` as a parameter, but just use it in the body of the function, so:

```
takeNum :: [Integer]
takeNum
  | totJum >= 10 = take 5 numList
  | totJum == 10  = numList
```

Note however that here you do not cover the case where `totJum` is less than or 10. In that case the function will thus error. You thus might want to add an `otherwise` clause.